# Main thread or background thread parse swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, parse-platform, swift3

For my settings I found a short cut to load data into my textfields. But I need to know if this is being performed on the main thread or background thread. I want this to be performed on the background thread but is the line below being executed on it or do I need to actually write, findobjectsinbackground like everything else.

```
FirstName.text = PFUser.current()?.object(forKey: "Name") as? String
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updating UI should be always on Main thread.**

```
let name = PFUser.current()?.object(forKey: "Name") as? String
```

Above line can be executed in background thread. But once you get the data from the `Parse Object`, you are updating the ui with the values, that should be on main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    FirstName.text = name;
}
```